# How to assign last element in array as the result of a different method?

Tags: java, arrays

I've created two different methods that calculate random monthly savings, and the monthly interest on those savings and saves each to its own array. I would like to have a new method that returns the last element in the calculateInterest array (as its the cumulative total of savings and interest in a year), so i can use that specific number in a different part of my program later.

So her is what i have so far. My methods for calculating savings and interest work just fine but i don't know how to actually get the value and not just the array number (which is all I've been able to call) in my last method.

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated!

```
public class EmployeeSavings extends AddressBook {

private double accountValue;
private double[] monthlyInterests = new double [12];
private double[] monthlySavings = new double[12];
private static final double MONTHLY_RATE= 0.00417;

public double[] generateMonthlySavings() {

    double min = 100;
    double max = 800;
    double range = (max - min);

    for (int i = 0; i < monthlySavings.length; i++) {
        monthlySavings[i] = (Math.random() * range) + min;

         System.out.println(monthlySavings[i]);

    }

    return monthlySavings;

}

public double[] calculateInterest() {

    double count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < monthlyInterests.length; i++) {

        if (i <= monthlyInterests.length)
            count = (monthlySavings[i] + count) * (1 + MONTHLY_RATE);

        System.out.println(count);
    }

    return monthlyInterests;

}

public double[] getMonthlyInterest(){
    return monthlyInterests;

}

public double[] getMonthlySavings() {
    return monthlySavings;

}

// Would like to return total value here
public double getAccountValue() {

    for (int i = 12; i <= getMonthlyInterest().length; i++) {

        accountValue = i; 

    }

    return accountValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your java version is 8 I would do it like so

```
public double getAccountValue() {
    return DoubleStream.of( getMonthlyInterest() ).sum();
}
```

It's much shorter and I think it's also more readable. But if your java version isn't 8 do something like this

```
double[] d = getMonthlyInterest();
double value = 0d;    

for (int i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
    value += d[i]; // d[i] returns value which has i index in array d.
}
```

Comment: Thats makes sense, how would i actually get the return statement to show the number..     value += d[11]... return value;   ?   Sorry new to programming!

Comment: @CheyBateman You would just return `value` variable. Why? Because every time for-loop runs it is increasing to at the end be sum of `getMonthlyInterest()`

Comment: @CheyBateman please accept my answer if it solved your problem. (should be green check under triangle facing down). Thank you!